# How to create an user with permission to do everything but drop databases?

Tags: sql-server, permissions

If it is easier, the user can be denied only deletion of one specific database instead of any database.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "everything"? Should the user be able to change server settings for instance or are we talking "all permissions within a database except the ability to drop it"?

Comment: @WorldWideDBA "all permissions within a database except the ability to drop it"

Comment: This requirement doesn't make a whole lot of sense. If I can drop every object in a database, I won't care about the lack of privileges for dropping the database itself -- I can still effectively destroy it.

Answer (score 3):

I assume by everything you mean db_owner rights.  Not Sysadmin rights.

If you can't trust them not to drop a database, they should not have access to most things you can do with Sysadmin.

What you want is described in the answer here https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/163437/21924

> So in effect, you can create a user that has all the rights of db_owner except say, managing users and dropping database. But I don't think there's a way to directly deny such privileges, you have to instead add everything but them.
>
> (See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189121.aspx)

Above is what you asked for, the solution most often used is just give the user db_owner.  Take regular backups, with the database in full recovery.  Take T-log backups as frequently as needed for your DR solution.

In the end it doesn't matter if a stupid user deleted the database or if the server crashed. Something happened to the database and you need to restore it. Your DR solution defines how much data the business can afford to loose. As it is probably a business user who has db_owner and deleted the database.  You have done your part as a DBA (*assuming your backup and restores work, you should test them regularly*)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use db_owner Not using Sysadmin.

And use Server Trigger to prevent delete database accidentally Like this :
To create a DDL trigger with server scope (ON ALL SERVER) or a logon trigger, requires CONTROL SERVER permission on the server

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions

```
CREATE TRIGGER Drop_Database ON ALL SERVER
FOR DROP_DATABASE
AS
BEGIN
    IF( ORIGINAL_LOGIN() = 'SomeUser')
    BEGIN
        Declare  @user nvarchar(1000)
        Set @user = 'Dropping of databases has been disabled on this server.'

        RAISERROR(@user, 16,1);
        ROLLBACK;
    END
END
```

But Of course i agree with James Jenkins for take care of your database (take backup / set right permission and etc ...)